# ListView evaluating item template with multiple variables

Tags: asp.net, .net, listview, data-binding

I am attempting to print out a line which contains an image tag within my ListView controller's Item Template.  I have tried this multiple ways with no success.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr id="itemTemplate" runat="server">
    <td>
      <asp:Literal ID="litImg" runat="server" Text='<%= "<img src="" & PathtoImg & "ProcessImage.aspx?Img=" & Eval("Img") & "&amp;PID="Resize"" alt=""ProductID"" />")))) %>' />
     </td>
     <td>
         <asp:Literal ID="litID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Department") %>' />
     </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The first eval does not work (and is a bit of a cluster) the second, simple line does.
It does not error, but it displays

> 

and obviously this doesn't work

```
<img src="<%= PathtoImg %>ProcessImage.aspx?Img=<%= Eval("Img")%>&amp;PID=Resize" alt="ProductID" />
```

as it gives the error

> "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control. "

This is my first time using a Listview and I am very unfamiliar with these templates.  Is what I want - displaying a data item with a server variable within the src of an image tag - possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a code-behind function or runat="server" your HTML control:

**Markup:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr id="itemTemplate" runat="server">
    <td>
       <asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="<% GetImageUrl(Eval("Img"), PathToImg))%>"/>
     </td>   
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected string GetImageUrl(object img, string pathToImg)
{
     //example business logic, change for your needs
     //build your url etc....
     string imgPathFromDb = (string)img;

     return PathToImg + imgPathFromDb; 

}
```

Other option:

```
<img runat="server" src="<%# PathtoImg %>ProcessImage.aspx?Img=<%# Eval("Img")%>&amp;PID=Resize" alt="ProductID" />
```

Comment: sigh...Please tell me it is not that easy.  Off to try this and I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: I can be pretty thick sometimes, but I did finally get that to work.  I basically build the whole image tag in the codebehind and called it like so:   <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text='<%# GetImageURL(Eval("Img")) %>' />   It did not work either way using the image tag and just sending the src to it.  Thank you!